# UK English. Would like to know the sentence I wrote is correct or not

Tags: grammar

I didn't read (past tense) any of these messages

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to such an event in the past, both

*I **didn't** read* (simple past)

*I **haven't** read* (present perfect)

are possible in both AmE and BrE, but the 1st is  more common in AmE and the 2nd in BrE, but really **it depends on to which extent you want to establish a connection to the present (for which the present perfect is better).**

Famous British author:

> **Collected Letters Volume Three: Narnia, Cambridge and Joy ... C. S.
>   Lewis**, ‎Walter Hooper - 2009
>
> **I haven't read** any of the books you mention except Farrer's Glass of Vision (if that is the Bamptons)13 which I found v. good.